# service balancer between cloud run and app engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I currently have two services in GCP, one is Google App Engine Flexible Environment and the other is Cloud Run and the idea is that through a service balancer I can distribute the traffic between those 2 services. Does anyone know how I can proceed?

Comment: Could you plz share why you are implementing such design? I mean what is the use-case of balancing requests between a standalone container and a PaaS env?

Comment: On which criteria do you want to split the traffic and to distrubute it on AppEngine and the other part on Cloud Run?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I can only think of saving costs as a reason for such design, what do you think?

Comment: Ah, ok, no problem, the split between Cloud Run and App Engine flexible make sense for many reasons and it depends on your use case. My question is more technical: when a request comes in, on which criteria will you route it to App Engine, or on Cloud Run? Is it based on the domain? On the path? something else?

Comment: yeah, I got your point. maybe @linkon needs to add more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an [HTTP(S) Load Balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https) with two `backend-configs` one for `AppEngine` and the other for `CloudRun`.

Consider these notes:

- Your LB will direct requests to each `backend` depending on the `PATH` and each `backend` will handle balancing depending on the the specs that you have configured for this `backend`.
- You will create and configure each `backend` separately. and both will be of type `Serverless Network Endpoint Group (Serverless NEG)`, See [here](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-https-serverless) for details.